# Why is my Json showing this unwanted array

Tags: asp.net, json, api

So I'm making a ASP.NET Web API app.  I have noticed that there is an array at the end of my Json body(I believe is my ICollection) How can I get rid of it?  `JsonIgnore` isn't working (maybe I am doing it wrong). I can also not use the `.ThenInclude()` to drill into that class in entity framework core, it throws an error and I was reading there is a bug when using this method currently in my version.

Here is what I was trying to describe:

[image]

Here is the API in debug:

[image]

Here is the model for TblModelName:

[image]

Any help would be great

Comment: I don't see a `[JsonIgnore]` attribute, so try adding one. What JSON Serializer are you using? There's a JsonIgnore in System.Text.Json.Serialization (which is part of the framework since  .net core 3) and one in Newtonsoft.Json (which is an external library). Be sure to resolve to the correct one, ie for the serializer you are using.

Comment: I did have them in, but removed them.  I tried both System.Text.Json.Serialization and Newtonsoft.Json.  Where should I place it?  and how do I resolve?  I'm ripping my hair out over this :D.

Comment: An annotation must be placed at the property which you want to annotate. As `TblModelDetails` is virtual, it may also be necessary to annotate the property in the subclasses (if existing). To use the correct one, just use the fully qualified name like `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]` or `[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]` depending on which serializer you are using

Comment: Thank you so so much.  I have it working now thanks to your help :D